# Submitting data to existing form is being rejected

Tags: html, forms, post

I am trying to submit data to a form that already exists, but from a different page.  The page we are submitting to is part of an existing application that we cannot change.  I have created a page to send the post, but the data is being rejected by the server.

My code to post the data is:

```
<form action='http://www.website.net/admin/webporta/Booking.aspx?code=FM13' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='ScriptManager1' value='upd_coverage|link_dailyLiab'>
<input type='hidden' name='__EVENTTARGET' value='link_dailyLiab'>
<input type='hidden' name='__EVENTARGUMENT' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='__LASTFOCUS' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='__VIEWSTATE' value='%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%2FrmBhPyyQ3qp%2FX%2BCz'>
<input type='hidden' name='inp_partnerCode' value='FM13'>
<input type='hidden' name='ddk_ins_sum' value='14999.0000'>
<input type='hidden' name='ddl_VehAnio' value='2015'>
<input type='hidden' name='ddl_mc' value='Auto/SUV/Pick Up/Cargo &amp; Passengers Van/Light Truck up to 2.5 ton of capacity'>
<input type='hidden' name='rbl_term' value='Daily'>
<input type='hidden' name='ddl_days' value='4'>
<input type='hidden' name='ddl_tpl' value='$150,000'>
<input type="Submit">test</input>
</form>
```

When I use wireshark to track the request I see that the following is a good request from the existing app that is accepted:

```
POST /admin/webportal/QQ.aspx?code=FM13 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thehost.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.thehost.net/admin/webportal/QQ.aspx?code=FM13
Content-Length: 3452
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pocb0l45qrufu355rx1tmd55; acopendivids=info01,info02,info03,info04,info05; acgroupswithpersist=nada; submenuheader=0c,1c,2c
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache

ScriptManager1=upd_coverage|link_dailyLiab&__EVENTTARGET=link_dailyLiab&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2FrmBhPyyQ3qp%2FX%2BCz&inp_partnerCode=FM13&ddl_ins_sum=14999.0000&ddl_VehAnio=2015&ddl_mc=Auto%2FSUV%2FPick%20Up%2FCargo%20%26%20Passengers%20Van%2FLight%20Truck%20up%20to%202.5%20ton%20of%20capacity&rbl_term=Daily&ddl_days=4&ddl_tpl=%24150%2C000&
```

However my form is creating the following post:

```
POST /admin/webportal/Booking.aspx?code=FM13 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thehost.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://newwebapp.com/buy.php?type=fullFull
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pocb0l45qrufu355rx1tmd55; acopendivids=info01,info02,info03,info04,info05,info06,info07; acgroupswithpersist=nada; submenuheader=0c,1c,2c
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 3431

ScriptManager1=upd_coverage%7Clink_dailyLiab&__EVENTTARGET=link_dailyLiab&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMjAzNDMwNzg2NA9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgYCBQ8WAh4Dc3JjBR1ncmFmaWNvcy9oZWFkZXJfbWV4Ym9yZGVyLmpwZ2QCBw9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIBDxYCHgVzdHlsZQUpYmFja2dyb3VuZC1pbWFnZTp1cmwoJ2ltZy9pbWdfYmdfcXEuanBnJykWAmYPZBYEZg9kFg4CAQ8QZBAVFAkkNSwwMDAuMDAJJDksOTk5LjAwCiQxNCw5OTkuMDAKJDE5LDk5OS4wMAokMjQsOTk5LjAwCiQyOSw5OTkuMDAKJDM0LDk5OS4wMAokMzksOTk5LjAwCiQ0NCw5OTkuMDAKJDUwLDAwMC4wMAokNTUsMDAwLjAwCiQ2MCwwMDAuMDAKJDY1LDAwMC4wMAokNzAsMDAwLjAwCiQ3NSwwMDAuMDAKJDgwLDAwMC4wMAokODUsMDAwLjAwCiQ5MCwwMDAuMDAKJDk1LDAwMC4wMAskMTAwLDAwMC4wMBUUCTUwMDAuMDAwMAk5OTk5LjAwMDAKMTQ5OTkuMDAwMAoxOTk5OS4wMDAwCjI0OTk5LjAwMDAKMjk5OTkuMDAwMAozNDk5OS4wMDAwCjM5OTk5LjAwMDAKNDQ5OTkuMDAwMAo1MDAwMC4wMDAwCjU1MDAwLjAwMDAKNjAwMDAuMDAwMAo2NTAwMC4wMDAwCjcwMDAwLjAwMDAKNzUwMDAuMDAwMAo4MDAwMC4wMDAwCjg1MDAwLjAwMDAKOTAwMDAuMDAwMAo5NTAwMC4wMDAwCzEwMDAwMC4wMDAwFCsDFGdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnFgECAmQCAw8QZA8WOWYCAQICAgMCBAIFAgYCBwIIAgkCCgILAgwCDQIOAg8CEAIRAhICEwIUAhUCFgIXAhgCGQIaAhsCHAIdAh4CHwIgAiECIgIjAiQCJQImAicCKAIpAioCKwIsAi0CLgIvAjACMQIyAjMCNAI1AjYCNwI4FjkQBQQyMDE2BQQyMDE2ZxAFBDIwMTUFBDIwMTVnEAUEMjAxNAUEMjAxNGcQBQQyMDEzBQQyMDEzZxAFBDIwMTIFBDIwMTJnEAUEMjAxMQUEMjAxMWcQBQQyMDEwBQQyMDEwZxAFBDIwMDkFBDIwMDlnEAUEMjAwOAUEMjAwOGcQBQQyMDA3BQQyMDA3ZxAFBDIwMDYFBDIwMDZnEAUEMjAwNQUEMjAwNWcQBQQyMDA0BQQyMDA0ZxAFBDIwMDMFBDIwMDNnEAUEMjAwMgUEMjAwMmcQBQQyMDAxBQQyMDAxZxAFBDIwMDAFBDIwMDBnEAUEMTk5OQUEMTk5OWcQBQQxOTk4BQQxOTk4ZxAFBDE5OTcFBDE5OTdnEAUEMTk5NgUEMTk5NmcQBQQxOTk1BQQxOTk1ZxAFBDE5OTQFBDE5OTRnEAUEMTk5MwUEMTk5M2cQBQQxOTkyBQQxOTkyZxAFBDE5OTEFBDE5OTFnEAUEMTk5MAUEMTk5MGcQBQQxOTg5BQQxOTg5ZxAFBDE5ODgFBDE5ODhnEAUEMTk4NwUEMTk4N2cQBQQxOTg2BQQxOTg2ZxAFBDE5ODUFBDE5ODVnEAUEMTk4NAUEMTk4NGcQBQQxOTgzBQQxOTgzZxAFBDE5ODIFBDE5ODJnEAUEMTk4MQUEMTk4MWcQBQQxOTgwBQQxOTgwZxAFBDE5NzkFBDE5NzlnEAUEMTk3OAUEMTk3OGcQBQQxOTc3BQQxOTc3ZxAFBDE5NzYFBDE5NzZnEAUEMTk3NQUEMTk3NWcQBQQxOTc0BQQxOTc0ZxAFBDE5NzMFBDE5NzNnEAUEMTk3MgUEMTk3MmcQBQQxOTcxBQQxOTcxZxAFBDE5NzAFBDE5NzBnEAUEMTk2OQUEMTk2OWcQBQQxOTY4BQQxOTY4ZxAFBDE5NjcFBDE5NjdnEAUEMTk2NgUEMTk2NmcQBQQxOTY1BQQxOTY1ZxAFBDE5NjQFBDE5NjRnEAUEMTk2MwUEMTk2M2cQBQQxOTYyBQQxOTYyZxAFBDE5NjEFBDE5NjFnEAUEMTk2MAUEMTk2MGcWAQIBZAIFDxBkZBYBZmQCBw8QZGQWAWZkAgkPZBYCAgEPEGRkFgECA2QCCw8QZGQWAWZkAg8PZBYEZg9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAQIBZAIBD2QWAgIBDxBkEBUKCSQ1LDAwMC4wMAkkOSw5OTkuMDAKJDE0LDk5OS4wMAokMTksOTk5LjAwCiQyNCw5OTkuMDAKJDI5LDk5OS4wMAokMzQsOTk5LjAwCiQzOSw5OTkuMDAKJDQ0LDk5OS4wMAokNTAsMDAwLjAwFQoJNTAwMC4wMDAwCTk5OTkuMDAwMAoxNDk5OS4wMDAwCjE5OTk5LjAwMDAKMjQ5OTkuMDAwMAoyOTk5OS4wMDAwCjM0OTk5LjAwMDAKMzk5OTkuMDAwMAo0NDk5OS4wMDAwCjUwMDAwLjAwMDAUKwMKZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZxYBZmQCAQ9kFhICAw9kFgICAQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFATRkZAIFDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaBYCAgQPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwIFBTYwLjAxZGQCCQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUFMzcuNjhkZAILDw8WAh8CBQU5NC44OGRkAg8PDxYCHwIFBjEyNy43NmRkAhMPDxYCHwIFBjEyNy45MGRkAhcPDxYCHwIFBjE3OC40OWRkAhsPZBYKAgEPZBYCAgEPDxYCHwIFBTU2LjU3ZGQCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMTkwLjUxZGQCAw9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMjMzLjQ4ZGQCBA9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMjc1LjAzZGQCBQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMzQxLjEzZGQCHQ9kFggCAg9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMjIxLjUwZGQCAw9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMjczLjc1ZGQCBA9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGMzIyLjcwZGQCBQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAgUGNDAzLjA5ZGQCDQ8PFgIfAgUZQ09OVEFDVCBVUyAxLTgwMC0zMzItMjExOGRkZHhPbrBpgvz%2FrmBhPyyQ3qp%2FX%2BCz&inp_partnerCode=FM13&ddk_ins_sum=14999.0000&ddl_VehAnio=2015&ddl_mc=Auto%2FSUV%2FPick+Up%2FCargo+%26+Passengers+Van%2FLight+Truck+up+to+2.5+ton+of+capacity&rbl_term=Daily&ddl_days=4&ddl_tpl=%24150%2C000
```

Any idea what I can do to get my post to be accepted by the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that you're posting to a parametrized url? I believe you can only perform GET and POST requests independently of one another, not in tandem. Try submitting "FM13" as another hidden field named "code".

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Unfortunately it didn't make a difference. It seems like the original app is posting like this as well.